# ubuntu 18.04 has experienced an internal error when running in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I was getting this error every few minutes on my Ubuntu 18.04 VM running inside Oracle VirtualBox. Inspecting the details showed a SIGSEGV in gnome-shell. Also, Visual Studio Code would never open properly (but I'm not sure if that was caused by this gnome-shell crash or whether both were a symptom of the same underlying problem).

The VM was brand new, based on the Ubuntu 18.04 VirtualBox image from osxboxes.org, running on a Dell latitude E5570. I created another VM based on the same image and got the exact same problem. However, doing the same thing on a different host (Dell XPS-13) worked fine (both hosts running Windows 10 Pro). So somehow I think the problem must be specific to the host hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the Ubuntu installation media and did my own installation from scratch and everything was fine.